# Expect command does not complete in cron

Tags: unix, cron, expect

I have the following script to copy the file from remote server. When I run the job manually it runs fine. 
When I run the file through cron, it aborts in between(copys only portion of the file, The file size is about 1GB).

No error log is created.

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_NAME=asda_email_success_log.sh
LOG_FILE=/home/xxxxxxx/logs/$SCRIPT_NAME'_'`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`.log
ERROR_FILE=/home/xxxxxxx/logs/$SCRIPT_NAME'_'`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`.error

date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
echo 'Current date is ' $date
date_minus_1day=$(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d')
echo 'Date minus one day is :', $date_minus_1day
set timeout 1800

expect -c "
spawn sftp -oPort=xxxx wmasdaftp@xxx.xxx.x.xx
expect \"Password\"
send \"xxxxxxxxxxxxx\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"get log/success.log.processed-$date_minus_1day /home/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxs/\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"bye\r\"
interact"
```

Comment: Is that `set timeout 1800` supposed to be run by `expect`? Because it isn't here. It is being run by the shell and not doing what you might have wanted it to.

Comment: before I set the set time out 1800 it was breaking even when I run it manually. After i set the timeout, it at least completely copies the file when i submit the the job manually. I agree the timeout might run only by shell this way. Not sure, how to put it in for expect. I have expect for other two jobs which runs successfully, as the file size is smaller.

Comment: Run in the shell like that `set timeout 1800` sets `$1=timeout` and `$2=1800` that can't affect the running of `expect` in any way. If you ran that *inside* expect then it would set the `expect` timeout to that value and *would* affect things. To run it in expect you stick it in the expect command you are running. (Using single quotes for most of the command would greatly simplify the string and keep you from needing to escape every double quote.)

Comment: I tried the following, it didn't work. Can you give me the syntax please.

Comment: expect -c "
set timeout 1800
spawn sftp -oPort=2222 wmasdaftp@xxx.xxx.x.xx
expect \"Password\"
send \"sssssss\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"get log/success.log.processed-$date_minus_1day /home/xxxx_crm_xxx/xxxx/\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"bye\r\"
interact"

Comment: @Manic, while you can't format comments like you want, that looks right. I would put an infinite timeout as the first line of the expect body: `set timeout -1`

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to use ssh public keys. Also, can you use `scp` instead of `sftp`?